# Refreshing an access token received from Google Identity Services / React App

Tags: reactjs, jwt, access-token, refresh-token, google-identity

I have a trouble right now with an access token received from Google Identity Services.

Some details about the case. I have full stack application, back-end based on **Spring/Webflux/Hibernate-Reactive** and frond end based on **React**. I'm using the google login feature from Google Identity Services with this react library **@react-oauth/google**.

I'm using the received "credential" after successful login for back-end access. Everything works like expected except that there is no refresh token in the response after successful login. The token expires after 1 hour and a user must be prompted to login again to receive a new token, which is horrible!

So, how to refresh this token, any Idea?

I could not found more info on google side, that's why I am writing here.

Answer (score 5):

So I found the solution by myself. I will post it here, with hope to help someone else who is struggling with this problem.

So using the react library **@react-oauth/google** I used the **useGoogleLogin** hook. I added "**flow: 'auth-code'**" to function's options object.

```
const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: codeResponse => console.log(codeResponse),
    flow: 'auth-code',
});
```

The function is triggered by click on simple button.

After successful login from the user, in the response object we can find a **code** property. We can exchange the **code** for an access,refresh and id token by calling the google oauth2 api:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=your_client_id' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=your_client_secret' \
--data-urlencode 'code=recieved_code_after_login' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=one of your redirect uri's listed in your 
credential'
```

after successful request access,refresh and id token are received.

refreshing the token also so simple:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=your_client_id' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=your_client_secret' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=received_refresh_token'
```

Here is the original Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_3

!important!
Remember that the refresh is valid until access is revoked. When you refresh the tokens, a new refresh token is not coming with the response. For further refreshes, you can use the same refresh token, receive by exchange.

Comment: You rock Petar! Works perfectly.